# Windows 2003 vs 2008 server. Any major drawbacks?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, vps

I'm currently running Windows Server 2008 on my 1024mb VPS. Everything is fine but the memory tends to stay high a little.

1. I want to run a web and mail server. So here are my questions :
2. Is there any major drawbacks like missing technologies? Will I be able to run Web Deploy, ASP.NET MVC 3, iis7, etc ?
3. Will there be a noticeable difference in speed and memory?
4. Is it as easy to configure as 2008?
5. Non-related question : I'm looking for a good free mail server, any suggestions? (pop, imap, smtp, webmail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a big difference. Win2k8 has IIS 7.x Win2k3 has IIS 6. End of story. You can't upgrade IIS independent of the OS.

Comment: Oh this sucks a LOT. Damn it...

Comment: On top, 2008 actually deals with less memory better - so ;) You go the wrong direction. Just realize you possibly needmore than 1024mb ;)